# Get full respository specific version from CVS

Tags: cvs

Using the command

```
cvs -d <location of the remote CVS cvsroot> checkout <module name> -r <module version>
```

Only gets me the files associated with the `<module version>` commit, which is a fraction of the repository of interest.

How do I checkout the *whole* project as it was after the `<module version>` commit? I literally just want the code - no need to be able to commit after making the checkout.

**Update**
My current workaround is to checkout using the -D flag on the date of a specific revision, but this is just *slightly* more clunky than seems reasonable...

Answer (score 0):

So the more I look at this the more I think my inability to do this is a lack of semantic understanding on my part. It seems that in CVS, *files* have versions, not the entire project. Asking for a *project* associated with some version is a nonsensical idea.

Instead, using the -D option achieves what I want, and seems, in hindsight, be the correct way to do this. Hopefully all this helps someone else out!